# hyphenation and justifying in \epigraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation, epigraphs

Is it possible to justify and hyphenate quotes typeset within an `\epigraph`?

An MWE and its output are shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{\blindtext}{source}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}`. See section 2.3 of the `epigraph` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{\blindtext}{source}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "manual for details" doesn't apply here. I had to find this answer to get the detail I was looking for. The manual doesn't explain when to redefine a command as a command and when to redefine it as an argument. For people without deeper knowledge of LaTeX who can't differentiate one from the other on the fly, reading an abriged manual like that can prove challenging.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{\justifying\blindtext}{source}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but requires adding `\justifying` for every instance of `\epigraph` in the text body. It's preferable to use a one-time switch in the preamble.